# Display analog input every 200ms in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am reading/writing data from a PLC using ModbusTCP and I need to be able to control Digital Outputs as well as read Analog Inputs. I am very new to Python, and have no trouble with the Digital Output signals, however I am unable to display the constantly changing values of the analog input in the tkinter GUI. I can get the analog signals separately but cannot put it all together

I have tried using `after` and other solutions, but when I'm able to get the analog values, it takes over the program and that's all that I get.

The goal is to show control for the Digital Output signals and at the same time update the analog values to the screen

Here is my code (again, I am new to python):

```
import time
from threading import Thread, Lock
from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient
from functools import partial
from tkinter import *

# init Wago ModBus Connection
c = ModbusClient(host='192.168.1.50', port=502, auto_open=True, debug=False)

window=Tk()

# set global
regs = []

# init a thread lock
regs_lock = Lock()


def polling_thread():
    global regs, regs_lock
    c = ModbusClient(host='192.168.1.50', port=502, auto_open=True)
    while True:
        # do modbus reading on socket
        reg_list = c.read_holding_registers(0, 1)
        # if read is ok, store result in regs (with thread lock)
        if reg_list:
            with regs_lock:
                regs = list(reg_list)
        # 1s before next polling
        time.sleep(1)

# start polling thread
tp = Thread(target=polling_thread)
# set daemon: polling thread will exit if main thread exit
tp.daemon = True
tp.start()

def get_analog():
# display loop (in main thread)
        while True:
    # print regs list (with thread lock synchronization)
            with regs_lock:
                list_string = map(str, regs)
                print("".join(list_string))
                analog_value_x="".join(list_string)
            # 1s before next print
            time.sleep(100/1000)
            window.after(100, get_analog)

get_analog()
test_label = Label(textvariable=analog_value_x)
test_label.pack()

def xreverse(duration):
    duration = float(x_pulse_duration.get())
    on1 = c.write_single_coil(2, True)
    time.sleep(duration)
    off1 = c.write_single_coil(2, False)
    print(duration)

def x(duration):
    duration = float(x_pulse_duration.get())
    on1 = c.write_single_coil(2, True)
    time.sleep(duration)
    off1 = c.write_single_coil(2, False)
    print(duration)

def yreverse(duration):
    duration = float(y_pulse_duration.get())
    on1 = c.write_single_coil(0, True)
    time.sleep(duration)
    off1 = c.write_single_coil(0, False)
    print(duration)

def y(duration):
    duration = float(y_pulse_duration.get())
    on = c.write_single_coil(0, True)
    time.sleep(duration)
    off = c.write_single_coil(0, False)
    print(duration)

# add widgets here
# INPUT TEXT
x_pulse_duration=Entry(window, width=3, font=('Arial 24'))
x_pulse_duration.place(x=195, y=150)

y_pulse_duration=Entry(window, width=3, font=('Arial 24'))
y_pulse_duration.place(x=335, y=150)

# ANALOG INPUT DISPLAY
#x_lvdt=Entry(window, width=5, font=('Arial 16'), textvariable=get_analog())
x_lvdt=Entry(window, width=5, font=('Arial 16'))
x_lvdt.place(x=190, y=250)

y_lvdt=Entry(window, width=5, font=('Arial 16'))
y_lvdt.place(x=330, y=250)

# BUTTONS
move_x=Button(window, text="<", fg='blue', command=partial(xreverse, x_pulse_duration.get()))
move_x.place(x=180, y=200)

move_x_reverse=Button(window, text=">", fg='blue', command=partial(x, x_pulse_duration.get()))
move_x_reverse.place(x=220, y=200)

move_y=Button(window, text="<", fg='blue', command=partial(yreverse, y_pulse_duration.get()))
move_y.place(x=320, y=200)

move_y_reverse=Button(window, text=">", fg='blue', command=partial(yreverse, y_pulse_duration.get()))
move_y_reverse.place(x=360, y=200)

# LABELS
lbl=Label(window, text="pulse duration", fg='blue', font=("ARIAL", 10))
lbl.place(x=252, y=160)

xaxis=Label(window, text="X-AXIS", fg='blue', font=("ARIAL", 24))
xaxis.place(x=175, y=95)

yaxis=Label(window, text="Y-AXIS", fg='blue', font=("ARIAL", 24))
yaxis.place(x=325, y=95)

x_lvdt=Label(window, text="X LVDT", fg='blue', font=("ARIAL", 16))
x_lvdt.place(x=189, y=270)

y_lvdt=Label(window, text="Y LVDT", fg='blue', font=("ARIAL", 16))
y_lvdt.place(x=327, y=270)

#x_analog=Label(window, textvariable=window.after(3000, get_analog))
#x_analog.place(x=80, y=80)


window.title('Stage Control')
window.geometry("600x400+10+20")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need to use while loop if `.after()` is used.

Comment: You shouldn't EVER be doing `time.sleep` in a GUI app.  What you need to do is have a "state" variable that tells you what thing comes next, then call `after`.  So, in `xreverse`, do the `c.write_single_coil(2,True)` (you don't need `on1` here), then do a `window.after(duration*1000, xoff)`, and have `xoff` do the `c.write_single_coil(2,False)`.

Comment: thank you, how do I handle multiplying the float duration time by milliseconds and then passing that to `after` which expects an int?

Comment: @user206211 Just use `int()` to convert the float number to integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ever use `time.sleep`.  Here's a way to organize your callbacks:

```
def get_analog():
# print regs list (with thread lock synchronization)
    with regs_lock:
        list_string = ''.join(map(str, regs))
        print(list_string)
        analog_value_x.set(list_string)
    window.after(100, get_analog)

analog_value_x = Stringvar()

test_label = Label(textvariable=analog_value_x)
test_label.pack()
get_analog()

def xreverse(duration):
    duration = float(x_pulse_duration.get())
    c.write_single_coil(2, True)
    window.after(duration*1000, xreverse2)

def xreverse2():
    c.write_single_coil(2, False)
    print(duration)

def x(duration):
    duration = float(x_pulse_duration.get())
    c.write_single_coil(2, True)
    window.after(duration*1000, x2)

def x2():
    c.write_single_coil(2, False)

def yreverse(duration):
    duration = float(y_pulse_duration.get())
    c.write_single_coil(0, True)
    window.after(duration*1000, yreverse2)

def yreverse2():
    c.write_single_coil(0, False)

def y(duration):
    duration = float(y_pulse_duration.get())
    c.write_single_coil(0, True)
    window.after(duration*1000, y2)

def y2():
    c.write_single_coil(0, False)
```

### Followup

I've corrected your use of the `textvariable`.  You can't just assign an arbitrary variable to that, it has to be a special Tkinter type.  In this case, a `Stringvar`.  And you use `x.set` to change the varlu of that variable.

That also requires a change in the ordering, because you have to wait until the `Stringvar` has been created before you can start `get_analog`.

You shouldn't really need the `reg_lock`, because you're not doing any multithreading here.

Comment: thank you, I modified the code but still getting this error:


```def get_analog():
    # print regs list (with thread lock synchronization)
            with regs_lock:
                list_string = map(str, regs)
                #print("".join(list_string))
                analog_value_x="".join(list_string)```
            window.after(100, get_analog)


`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui5.py", line 47, in <module>
    test_label = Label(textvariable=analog_value_x)
NameError: name 'analog_value_x' is not defined`

Comment: It will take a bit of rearranging to fix that problem.  You don't update a Tk `textvariable` just by setting a new value.

Comment: Thank you, I just had to make `Stringvar` to `StringVar` and still use `analog_value_x.set("".join(list_string))` , but it works now. I will try and process your feedback and learn from it.

Comment: Did you not notice that I did the `''.join` when I created `list_string`, so I don't have to repeat that step?

Comment: I did not, but I do now. Removed the repeated step. Thanks again, you have been very helpful and it's much appreciated.

Comment: what if I wanted to do some math on the analog values so I can convert to distance?

 I have been trying to use `int(analog_value_x.get())` but it appears because it's a StringVar I can't do that

Comment: Sure you can.  Did you try it?  What happened?  However, you can also make it an `IntVar` instead, in which case Tkinter will do the conversion for you.

Comment: I changed the StringVar to IntVar, analog_value_x = IntVar() and tried to just do math on the Entry that displays the values

x_lvdt=Entry(window, width=5, justify=CENTER, font=('Arial 14'), textvariable=analog_value_x / 1290). I get this error.

 x_lvdt=Entry(window, width=5, justify=CENTER, font=('Arial 14'), textvariable=analog_value_x / 1290)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'IntVar' and 'int'